# Http post works in Postman but not in C# with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post, postman, dotnet-httpclient

If I made a Http (Https) post through Postman everything works fine. But if I tried the same post with the HttpClient in .NET core it won't work it seems like the Authorization failed or something like that because the `response.StatusCode` is OK but if I read the content string I get a HTML page with 404 and its asking me if I like to login.

Of course I already checked the obvious things like the address and I tried different tokens (they always worked in postman). I also tried different versions of adding the Bearer token:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

This is the code at the moment:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("www.baseaddress.de");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = object.Id }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/address", content);
```

Postman Headers:
[image: Postman headers]

The body:

[image: Postman body]

I also tried it with insomnia and it works perfectly there too. Maybe postman do something in its header which I don't know? What are the common differences between postman an HttpClient? Does anyone have any other suggestion about what I could do or try to find the mistake?

Edit:

Fixed it by adding the `/` behind the base address and deleting it in front of the call:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("www.baseaddress.de/");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"address", content);
```

Maybe anyone knows why the `/` is needed at the end of the base address, why can't I put it before the API call?

Comment: Is the certificate valid?

Comment: Yes. I just checked it again.

Comment: Use Postman's code generator to see the raw HTTP request and compare it to what you are doing in c#. Check that your BaseAddress ends with a slash `/`

Comment: I feel pretty stupid right now but after adding the `/` to the base address and deleting the `/` before the address it works. ... Why do i have to add the slash after my base address and cant use it in the `.PostAsync` method like "/address"? Please add your comment as answer I will accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: I have found the reason of this kind of issues, capturing and comparing the postman request vs HttpClient request through fiddler. May be that can give you a clue.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `new { id = object.Id }.ToString()` you need to do

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = object.Id })
```

Code like `new { id = 77 }.ToString()` produces `"{ id = 77 }"`, not `"{ id: "77" }"`

Comment: Getting still the same response. :(

Comment: @Genfood will not "fix" your curent problem, but you don't need `.ToString()` after `.SerializeObject`. It already returns the json string that you need.

Comment: @Genfood right now it looks like an address problem.Could you double check your request has corect final URL. Maybe you need to pass '"/address"', not just `address` as param. Also, try to use the whole URL in `.PostAsync` method: `http://address:port/address`

Comment: I added the slash right after my base address and everything works now Like @Crowcoder said. in my real code there was a / before the address just censored the URL.

Comment: Thank you @Genfood , spent a large amount of time spinning wheels until I ran across your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I changed the address from `http://...` to `https://...` and that fixed the issue.